# ¿Cómo desplegó una aplicación en el ROOT Context para que se pueda acceder a través de la URL: 192.168.1.n:8080?

Tags: tomcat, redes, despliegue

hasta ahora he desplegado una aplicación JSP (.WAR) y se escucha desde localhost(de forma local), necesito cambiar esa ip (127.0.0.1/localhost) por la ip de mi ordenador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he desplegado con un servidor de Apache Tomcat!

Comment: ¿Quieres que esté en red local o con acceso de internet?

Comment: Quiero que este en red local

Comment: Sabes la ip de tu maquina en la red? es lo que debes escribir en el navegador de la otra maquina, en caso que no se muestre debes revisar el firewall de tu maquin y permitirle conexiones al puerto 8080, en este caso